# How to display label before input tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to get labels before input tag in UI. But in my case I am getting output as show in below image.

Below is my code sample.
Please help me to make the changes so I can get the required output.

My code sample:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    Vector Name: <input name="vectorName" /><br/>
    Vector IP Address: <input type="password" name="ip"/><br/>
    Vector Serial Number: <input type="password" name="serial" /><br/> 
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please replace your code with:

```css
.block label{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 180px;
      text-align: right;
}
.block{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
      <div class="block">
          <label>Vector Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="vectorName" />
      </div>
      <div class="block">
          <label>Vector IP Address:</label>
          <input type="password" name="ip"/>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
          <label>Vector Serial Number:</label>
          <input type="password" name="serial"/>
      </div>
</form>
```